# C# style string implementation in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I'm trying out a C# style string implementation in C++.
I have created an object and a pointer for class String, and assigned the object to the pointer. When i try to modify the object via the pointer instead of modifying the existing object i want to create a new object and make the pointer point it.

So i have overloaded the "=" operator, and creating a new object in the operator overloaded method. In order to reflect the change i need to use `ss=*ss = "name";`

Any suggestion to improve this code.

Below is my sample code

```
class String
{
    char *str;
public:
    String(char* str_in)
    {
        str = new char[strlen(str_in)];
        strcpy(str, str_in);
    }
    String* operator=(char* s)
    {
        return new String(s);
    }
};
int main()
{
    String s="sample";
    String *ss;
    ss = &s;
    ss=*ss = "name";
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to modify the this pointer, but not working as expected

```
String *ptr;
ptr = const_cast<String*>(this);
ptr = new String(s);
```

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise? Is `std::string` not usable in your case?

Comment: Yes, Its just an exercise.

Comment: `ss=*ss = "name";` doesn't compile.

Comment: It compiles and works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some changes like this:

```
#include <string.h>

class String
{
    char *str;
public:
    String(const char* str_in)
    {
        str = new char[strlen(str_in)];
        strcpy(str, str_in);
    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }

    String& operator=(const char* s)
    {
        char* tmp = new char[strlen(s)];
        strcpy(tmp, s);
        delete [] str;
        str = tmp;
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    String s("sample");
    String *ss;
    ss = &s;
    ss = new String("name");
    delete ss;
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, you need an appropriate destructor or you are going to have a memory leak when String gets destroyed. Deleting the char* fixes this (since it is an array, we use the array delete).

Secondly, in C++, we almost always return a reference for operator= (not a pointer). So this revised operator= function is probably better - it deletes the old string, allocates memory for the new string, copies the new string, and returns *this.

Third, you can use const char* instead of char* for the constructor and assignment operator since you are not editing it.

In main(), I also created a new object for the pointer to point to since you requested that in the original post (and then it is deleted afterwards to avoid a memory leak).

Let me know if you have any questions with those changes.

Comment: In operator=, it's probably advisable to new & strcopy into a temp variable, then delete & replace str. This way, if new throws an exception, the object is unchanged.

Comment: Good point. I just edited it. Let me know if you think it looks good.

Comment: Looks much better. An upvote on muh original comment would be appreciated. thx!